# wxpython grid: multiple cell edit (ala Excel)

Tags: user-interface, datagrid, wxpython

I'm looking for a way for a user to edit data in bulk in a wxPython grid, a little like in Excel when you select a range, type data and press shift-Enter. This is a simplified version of my grid:

```
class MyGrid(gridlib.Grid):
    def __init__(self, panel):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, panel)
        self.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE, self.onEditCell)
        self.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_RANGE_SELECT, self.onSelection)

    def onSelection(self, event):
        if self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft() == []:
            self.selected_row_number = 0
            self.selected_col_number = 0
        else:
            self.selected_row_number = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][0] - self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0] + 1
            self.selected_col_number = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][1] - self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1] + 1
        print self.selected_row_number, self.selected_col_number

    def onEditCell(self,event):
        print self.selected_row_number, self.selected_col_number
```

The issue seems to be that the onEditCell event overwrites the previous selection. So I can select e.g. a four by four block in the grid, and onSelection will print 4 4. But when I start typing and press Enter, onEditCell will print 0,0 as if only the cell I'm editing was selected. How can I keep a "memory" of how many cells are selected? Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I can get it to work with an ugly hack that doesn't seem like the right way to do things:

```
def onSelection(self, event):
    self.previous_selected_row_number = self.selected_row_number
    self.previous_selected_col_number = self.selected_col_number
    if self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft() == []:
        self.selected_row_number = 0
        self.selected_col_number = 0
    else:
        self.selected_row_number = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][0] - self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][0] + 1
        self.selected_col_number = self.GetSelectionBlockBottomRight()[0][1] - self.GetSelectionBlockTopLeft()[0][1] + 1
    print self.selected_row_number, self.selected_col_number
    print self.previous_selected_row_number, self.previous_selected_col_number



def onEditCell(self,event):
    print self.previous_selected_row_number, self.previous_selected_col_number
```

If anyone can think of a better way...